# Is this an algorithm with O(4^n) complexity?

Tags: java, big-o, time-complexity

I am given a question to write a method with a time complexity of O(4^n).

I have came out with this algorithm:

```
public void test(int n){
   for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){
      test(4*i);
   }
}
```

Is this be considered to be running on O(4^n)?

Comment: This program runs forever for all original input greater than 1, so how should it be O(4^n)?

Comment: For solving your task: Do you know any algorithm with time complexity O(2^n)? Maybe you see a pattern there to manipulate that algorithm to end up with O(4^n) ;-)

Comment: @stefan: I do know about fibonacci being: fib(n) = fib(n-1)+fib(n-2). Is there a way I can modify this to become O(4^n)? Or can I do this: fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) + fib(n-3) + fib(n-4)?

Comment: If you can answer why `fib(n) = fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)` is O(2^n), then you're probably able to answer that question about `notfib(n) = notfib(n-1) + notfib(n-2) + notfib(n-3) + notfib(n-4)` yourself ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were quite close with your program. The correct function would go like this:

```
public void test(int n) {
  if (n == 0) return;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) test(n-1);
}
```

Run this piece of code to check:

```
static int runs;
static void test(int n) {
  runs++;
  if (n == 0) return;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) test(n-1);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
  for (int n = 1; n <= 5; n++) {
    runs = 0;
    test(n);
    System.out.format("%d: %d %d\n", n, 1<<(2*n), runs);
  }
}
```

It will print

```
1: 4 5
2: 16 21
3: 64 85
4: 256 341
5: 1024 1365
```

The run count is off by one, but the big-O complexity is satisfied.

The reasoning as to why it is O(4<sup>n</sup>) is probably quite obvious once you see it, but a little explanation cannot hurt. The function is best imagined to be solving a complex problem by divide-and-conquer. It reduces an *n*-sized problem to four instances of an (*n-1*)-sized problem, recursing until the subproblem is trivial (size 0). A problem of size 1 is therefore solved in 1+4 steps (entry-point call + 4 trivial subproblems); a problem of size 2 in 1 + 4*(1 + 4) = 21 steps, and so on.

Comment: Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime... You are giving too much fish!

Comment: @joxnas I teach by example. OP has already thought hard about it, tried to make his own code, and got stumped. I **corrected** his code, not write it from scratch. It is quite obvious from his attempt that he had already been following the line of thinking that you advised.

Comment: This is not "correcting" code, it's a completely different algorithm. I don't think the OP has really learned a thing about big-O with this answer.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I don't think that's obvious at all. It would be ok if you made up an analogous question and answered it allowing the op to understand the reasoning by analogy. Giving the answer right away to the exact same question he was asking seams a little too much. You should at least write a brief explanation of your reasoning.I believe OP can learn from that code.But I think there was more chances of him understanding this if he tried other approaches first. This is as much as an opinion as it is that the OP thinks your answer is the best for him in the short/mid/long term.

Comment: @joxnas I agree with the point that more explanation can't hurt. I may be biased (as I pointed out, this is all about opinion anyway) but I expect an a-ha effect froam that two-liner by anyone who has already banged his head enough to produce the code that OP posted. When at a full keyboard (at mobile ATM) I'll try to remember and add some explaining.

Comment: Hi all, The reason why I accepted this answer is because I have learnt the most compared to rest of the replies. Even before I asked the question, I have spend the whole day reading through books and internet searches to see if anything come close. I do understand what is required for an exponential complexity, but I have to admit, I was having problems implementing them onto code. 4^n is 4 * 4 * 4 for n times. I think at the point where there are concepts involved,  breaking down and learning from code can a good alternative way to go.

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't.

Calling test(0) will return immediately. So will calling test with a negative number.

Calling test with a positive number will never return (it will with overflow, but that's something you don't usually take into account when calculating complexity).

Comment: test(1) returns fast too since it degrades to test(1) -> test(0) return; return;

Answer (score 1):

No it is not. This program will run infinitely for number greater than 1. Hence its not of O(4^n)

Answer (score 1):

As it has been said, that will run forever for a given input greater than 1. To write a 4^n complexity program, try to think about an operation which  gets 4 times more complex for n than for n-1. For instance dividing a square in 4 smaller squares for n = 1, and then dividing those squares again for n = 2...

You will realize that the number of squares will be 4^n as so will the time complexity of the algorithm.

Understand however that the big o notation represents an upper bound, so any operation which is O(n) will also be O(4^n) but I guess that's not what's intended...